# Field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> I need to prove that if $F$ is a field and $u=\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} \in F(t)$ (where $f,g$ are coprime in $F[t]$) then $[F(t):F(u)]=\max(\deg f,\deg g)$.

I know I have to prove that $ug(x)-f(x)$ is irreducible in $F(u)[x]$, but I cannot do it. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing at least a condition that $f$ and $g$ be coprime.

Comment: Remember that $u$ is a transcendental, so you should think of it as just another letter. But as an element of $F[x][u]$, $g(x)\cdot u - f$ is of degree one (in $u$). That should help you.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful.

Comment: It’s considered fair for you to write up your own answer to your question. I’d give it a plus one, then!